# Google Api,Java, reading data from webpage

Tags: java, api

Can anybody help me on reading data from google webpage. for example:i want to read the links, author names below the links and PDF or HTML links on the right side to my database using Java.

Please find the link here:

http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=visualization&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C4&as_sdtp=

Comment: I noticed that you tried to suggest an edit on my answer with your code. Edit your original post and include your code along with the NullPointerException stack trace and we can look at it

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is called data extraction. You need to load the HTML page and then logically select the pieces of information from the HTML.

Start by using an HTML parser to read the HTML page and then look for the patterns in how Google lays out its scholar links. You might find that things are listed in an un-ordered list, or maybe certain elements have an identifying tag or class that you can use to extract the data you want.